# Why does the type not conform to protocol?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Let's have the following piece of code:

```
protocol ItemView {

    var image: UIImage? { get set }
}

 class BaseController<T: UIView where T: ItemView>: UIViewController {

    var itemView = T()
}

class ConcreteItemController: BaseController<UIImageView> {

}
```

For the BaseController I am getting an error message saying "Type "UIImageView" does not conform to protocol "ItemView"".

But why?

Same error message shows up when I do this instead:

```
 typealias ConcreteItemController = BaseController<UIImageView>
```

I am really missing something here...why would the UIImageView not conform to ItemView protocol? It HAS an optional image property..so where's the problem?

Comment: `UIImageView` doesn't declare that it conforms to `ItemView`

Comment: Oh right! I thought it's enough to conform without declaring it....why don't you put this as proper answer so that I can give you 10 credits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UIImageView` does not declare that it conforms to `ItemView`. Because swift is a strictly typed language, it doesn't infer conformance to protocols, as some types will only incidentally conform. You could however say something like:

```
protocol ItemView {

    var image: UIImage? { get set }
}

class BaseController<T: UIView where T: ItemView>: UIViewController {

    var itemView = T()
}

extension UIImageView: ItemView {}

class ConcreteItemController: BaseController<UIImageView> {

}
```

Comment: I wouldn't say "it's not smart enough". It's on purpose that a class doesn't conform to a protocol by coincidence, but only if it says so itself (and of course has only the necessary bits).